# R-Markdown: input and output with relative pathes

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am working on a project which is developed by our team. We share the codes in a repository. Every team member is using his/her own machine with his/her own working directories. That is why we use relative paths in our projects. Usually we use something like

```
setwd("MyUser/MyProject/MyWD/myCodesDir") # local
...
MyReportingPath <- "../ReportsDir" # in repository
```

Now I try to render a markdown report to this directory:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "relevantPath/ReportingHTML.Rmd",
                output_file = paste0(MyReportingPath, "/ReportingHTML.html"))
```

This doesn't work. It only works if I type in the full path of the output file ("/home/User/..../ReportingHTML.html")
This is one of the issues I would like to clarify: is there any possibility to use relative paths in any way for Markdown?

Second issue is that if I type in an non-existing directory in the output_file, pandoc throws me an error instead of creating this directory with my output file. Is there any possibility to do a dynamic output directory creation? (except for doing system(paste0("mkdir ", reportPath), intern = T) before rendering)

P.S. It is important for me to render the markdown document in a separate R function, where I create the whole environment which is inherited by my Markdown document.

Comment: Did you try the [`here` package](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here) and also the [`ezknitr` package](https://github.com/ropensci/ezknitr)?

Comment: Thank you, @romles . 
I have tried `ezknitr`, however, it didn't do well with YAML headers. That is why I decided not to use it.
`here()` gives me access to my current working directory and I can go deeper into it, thanks! But it doesn't allow me to go one or two directories above it, like
`../../DirectoryAbove`

That is why unfortunately I can't solve my issue that way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial issue - since you're using `paste0` you need to provide the `/` delimiter between your output directory and output file.

You wrote:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "relevantPath/ReportingHTML.Rmd",
            output_file = paste0(MyReportingPath, "ReportingHTML.html"))
```

Instead, try:

```
rmarkdown::render(input = "relevantPath/ReportingHTML.Rmd",
            output_file = paste0(MyReportingPath, "/", "ReportingHTML.html"))
```

More broadly:

For your first issue (settting the path for the input file) - I also  suggest using `here::here()`.  If you need to navigate up from your working directory you can break down the path as follows:

```
parent_dir <- paste(head(unlist(strsplit(here::here(), "/", fixed = TRUE)), -1), collapse = "/")
grandparent_dir <- paste(head(unlist(strsplit(here::here(), "/", fixed = TRUE)), -2), collapse = "/")
```

However - it might be easier to set the working directory to a higher level, then build up your code and results directories, for example:

```
project_dir <- here::here()
codefile <- paste(project_dir, "code", "myreport.Rmd", sep = "/")
outfile <- paste(project_dir, "results", "myreport.html", sep = "/")
rmarkdown::render(input = codefile,
            output_file = outfile))
```

For your second issue (creating the directory for output) - using `dir.create("MyReportingPath", recursive = TRUE)` will create the output directory and any intermediate levels.  You will get a warning if the directory exists which can be suppressed using `showWarnings = FALSE`.

Comment: Thank you, @DonJ, this solution should definitely work.
But it is kind of artificial. It seems, that there is no "nice" or "organic" solution, right?

Comment: I suggest fixing your `paste0` command first to see if that fixes it the issue first.  I edited my  answer to clarify.

Comment: `paste0` issue was actually fixed. I have a mistake in my question, but not in my working code, sorry. I have fixed my question text

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this myself, and as it turns out, there's one additional complication here: **You really do need to use an absolute path for the output if your input file being rendered isn't in your current working directory.**  You also need to use absolute paths for anything else during rendering, for example images like `![](path.png)`.

This looks to be because `rmarkdown::render` temporarily [sets your working directory](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/a75dc3727ae7acaba9f5b529d9ae895d911b09b7/R/render.R#L389) to the directory containing the input file, so it interprets a relative directory as relative to *that* path, not your initial working directory.  (EDIT: There's currently an [open issue](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2370) for this on github.)

For example if you have this setup:

```
subdir/test.Rmd
outdir
```

And you do this:

```
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "subdir/test.Rmd",
  output_file = "outdir/out.html")
```

You get the error:

```
Error: The directory 'outdir' does not not exist.
Execution halted
```

Instead, you could do:

```
output_path <- file.path(normalizePath("."), "outdir/out.html")
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "subdir/test.Rmd",
  output_file = output_path)
```

...and that should work.

You might think you could just use `normalizePath("outdir/out.html")`, but you can't, because that function only works when the path already exists.  You also might think you could do this:

```
rmarkdown::render(
  input = "subdir/test.Rmd",
  output_file = file.path(normalizePath("."), "outdir/out.html"))
```

but you can't, because R only gets around to interpreting the value of `output_file` once the working directory has already been changed.

Comment: That is a cool finding, Thank you!